# Joomla 1.5.24: Why does the user gets logged out?

Tags: php, session, joomla

We have a web site on Joomla 1.5.24.

The problem is that users get logged out when they try to see any page other than the main page.

For example:

- A user logs in.
- Everything is fine.
- The user wants to see any other page on the site.
- The user is not logged in anymore.

There is no problem with logging in. This problem occurred only today. We did not change any configurations or plugin ratings.

I saw on the [official joomla site](http://www.joomla.org/) that there is a bug that users might be logged out if the "Remember Me" plugin's rating is not prior to the "System Legacy" or "System Cache". But this isnt our case. I checked it.

Comment: update to the latest version of Joomla (1.5.26). Have you been fiddling with the database or Joomla core files?

Comment: I would update but currently we dont have time to back everything up and to make an update.And site is quite busy for now. 
No, for the past 2-3weeks we didnt do anything with the DB or joomla core files.

Comment: for the past 2-3 weeks? so before this you did do somethin with the database and/or core files?

Comment: Akeeba Backup is very nice for quick backups.  http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/backup/1606

Comment: @Lodder we didn't change core Joomla files. but the company which did the template for us might have changed mod_login. not sure about it though.

Comment: to be honest I dont see the point in akeeba backup. I find it easier to simply zip the ftp and download it, same goes for the bd. I would recommend you talk to the company and find out if they changed mod_login or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing significant happened before the error started occurring, it might be an issue with your cache.  Try clearing Joomla's cache with [Cache Cleaner.](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/cache/9495)

Comment: Yesterday in order to find some hints, I googled and read so many posts. I did clear the cache. I thought the problem is with sessions. And tried to change the session handling to the NONE, but no change. I really need to fix this. Users are not happy :(

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody will have a similar problem. Here is the solution and a little bit of a explanation.

Problem was in DB connection.We put a module where we had our own piece of code. & one of the developers initialized a new DB connection and the session was lost because of it. So be sure that you are not using the same $db variable name. We found this error by checking line by line of the index page and debugging every step.

Hope it will save time of other developers :)